# Facebook session using SLRequest in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, slrequest, facebook-sdk-3.1, acaccountstore

I have to send app request using facebook sdk as it was not possible through graph call. I have already got my facebook token as well as SLRequest object with access permission granted(yes). I just want to create fb session using above two parameters so that user does not have to enter his credentials on the pop up and the credentials will be automatically taken from SLrequest or Accounts object or from access token.

Comment: I got the same problem. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: @sahara108 yes i found the solution finally, pls read the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the solution, call the requestGrantedForFb just after you get your request granted from account store   :

```
-(void)requestGrantedForFb
{
 if (gblAppDelegate.session.isOpen)
    {
        [self SendReqClk];
 } else
{
    if (gblAppDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated)
    {
        gblAppDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
    }


    NSArray *permissionArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_friendlists",@"basic_info",nil];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissionArray
                                           allowLoginUI:YES
                                      completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {

                                          if (session.isOpen)
                                          {
                                              gblAppDelegate.session = session;
                                              [self SendReqClk];

                                          } else
                                          {
                                              gblAppDelegate.session = session;

                                          }


                                      }];
    });
}
}
```

After that

```
-(void)SendReqClk
{



NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                    dataWithJSONObject:@{
                                         @"social_karma": @"5",
                                         @"badge_of_awesomeness": @"1"}
                    options:0
                    error:&error];
if (!jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"JSON error: %@", error);
    return;
}

NSString *giftStr = [[NSString alloc]
                     initWithData:jsonData
                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableDictionary* params = [@{@"data" : giftStr} mutableCopy];

// Display the requests dialog
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [FBWebDialogs
     presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:gblAppDelegate.session
     message:@"Welcome to !!! "
     title:@"Join now !!!"
     parameters:params
     handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             // Error launching the dialog or sending the request.
             NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
         } else {
             if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                 // User clicked the "x" icon
                 NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

             } else {
                 // Handle the send request callback
                 NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
                 if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"request"]) {
                     // User clicked the Cancel button
                     NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

                 } else if(result== FBWebDialogResultDialogCompleted){
                     // User clicked the Send button
                     NSString *requestID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"request"];
                     UIAlertView *aAlertSuccess=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Friend request sent successfully!!!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                     [aAlertSuccess show];
                     NSLog(@"Request ID: %@", requestID);
                     //                     [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(stopActivity) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
                     //                     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"my alert" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];//
                     //                     [alert setTag:125];
                     //                     [alert show];

                 }
             }
         }
     }];

});

}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I also find this solution. But I simply do `[FBSession setActiveSession:session];` in the callback. From now on, I can use with FB Sdk normally :P